# showing if $ x\equiv_my\rightarrow\frac{x}{r}=\frac{y}{r}$

Tags: relations

How would I show this proposition.

$ x\equiv_my\rightarrow\frac{x}{r}=\frac{y}{r}$

I will make $\frac{x}{r}$ capital X because it is easier to write. And $\frac{y}{r}$ capital Y. These are the equivalence classes.

I did this

Let w be any object. Let $w \in X$ thus $x\equiv_mw$. Since the mod is equivalent relationship it is symmetric.

Thus $y\equiv_mx$ and since $w\in Y$, $y\equiv m_w$.

In conclusion

X=Y.

Comment: does $\equiv_m$ refer to $x \equiv y \pmod{m}$

Comment: yes sorry indeed

Comment: for example 7= 4 mod 3 is true because 7-3 is divisible by 4

Comment: Perhaps it's my naivety, but it feels like some details are missing.. what is $m_{w}$? How does $\equiv_{m} w$ relate to $\equiv m_w$? What is $r$ and does it relate to $m$?

Comment: The notation is a little unusual.  I will suppose that $R$ is the relation, and that you want to show that $x/R=y/R$. Start as you did, let $w\in x/R$. Then $w\equiv x\pmod{m}$ and since $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$, by transitivity we have $w\equiv y\pmod{m}$, and therefore $w\in y/R$. Similarly, if $w\in y/R$, we can show that $w\in x/R$. The result follows.

Comment: @Nico After deep though on this proposition I think the class X/R is equivalent to x mod(m), and w is particular case in this class X/R called equivalance class.

Comment: Now To work on the transient part

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in the thing here it is.

Let $w\in X$. This means that w is actually one the equivalent classes of mod for example congruence modulo 5 will have 0,1,2,3,4 as it cases.

$x\equiv 1 \mod 5$ is what x subtract by 1 is divisible by 5.

So then you do $x\equiv
 w\mod (m)$. By the symetry $y\equiv
 x \mod(m)$ then by the transitivity

$y=w \mod(m)$.

Thus $w\in Y$

Thus X is subset of Y.

Now to types the rest later time.